# How to find the differences between the values of a specific column based on a key?

Tags: mysql

I've two tables as purchase_details and invoice_details

and i want to store the inventory/stock of each product from the data of these two tables.

structure of **purchase_details**.

```
'pid', 'int(10)'
'product_id', 'int(10)' 
'quantity', 'float(8,2)'
'amount', 'float(12,2)'
'expiry_date', 'date'
```

structure of **invoice_details**.

```
'invoice_id', 'int(10) unsigned'
'product_id', 'int(10) unsigned'
'quantity', 'float(10,2)'
'price', 'float(12,2)'
```

i want to calculate the total quantity of remaining stock 
(quantity of sum of products from purchase_details) - (quantity of sum of products from invoice_details)

Product_id is would be same for the two tables.

**Product** table consists of product data,  and the structure is

```
'id', 'int(10) unsigned'
'cid', 'int(10) unsigned'
'name', 'varchar(90)'
'selling_price', 'float(10,2)'
'mrp', 'float(10,2)'
'reorder_level', 'bigint(20) unsigned'
```

the invoice_details may or may not have entries for every product_id.

how can i proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  ( sum(purchase_details.quantity) - sum(invoice_details.quantity)) as stock  
    from products 
    left outer join purchase_details 
    on products.product_id == purchase_details.product_id
    left outer join invoice_details  
    on  products.product_id  =  invoice_details.product_id 
    group by products.product_id
```

this will give you the stock for each product and you can add your where statement if you need certain products

```
select  ( sum(purchase_details.quantity) - sum(invoice_details.quantity)) as stock  
    from products 
    left outer join purchase_details 
    on products.product_id == purchase_details.product_id
    left outer join invoice_details  
    on  products.product_id  =  invoice_details.product_id 
    where products.product_id = 137
    group by products.product_id
```

Comment: It returns wrong value.. 
I've 136 for product id 7 and 20 for product id 8 in purchase, 12 for product id 7 in invoice , so total should be 124 for productid 7 and 20 for product id 8 .. But its returing 224 and null

Comment: because you need to call the product table first , i will modify the statement take a look

Comment: no its still not working
My product table has unique ids but the product_id may be repeated in both purchase_details and invoice_details.

Comment: yeah i know if the products table have unique id then this should work the only thing u need to add check if the value is null make it = 0

Comment: any way i can add check to make it 0 but the total is coming as wrong for other,  i dont know why it happens? the total should be 124 but it is returning as 224

Answer (score 1):

This one is my new answer, already tested on sqlserver. I am not sure about mysql

```
select pro.id, SUM(pro.quantity - inv.quantity)
from (select sum(p.quantity) as quantity, p.id as id from product p group by p.id) as pro, 
     (select sum(i.quantity) as quantity, i.id as id from invoice i group by i.id) as inv
where inv.id = pro.id
group by pro.id;
```

Comment: its not working.. i've multiple products in product table. And product_id will be repeated in both purchase_details and invoice_details table. And i want to calc stock for each and every product

Comment: uhm, that means, you want to list the stock (the difference) for every product id?

Comment: i tried the following query but the results r not great.

    select a.pid, a.amount - b.amount from (select product_id as pid, COALESCE(sum(quantity),0) amount from purchase_details group by product_id) a, (select product_id as pid, COALESCE(sum(quantity), 0) amount from invoice_details group by product_id) b group by a.pid;

that returns
7, 124.00  
8, 8.00

but it should be 7,124.00 and 8,20 
for 7 the value are 136 in purchase and sales 12 so its correct as 124 
but for 8 the purchase is 20 and sales has no values but even it subtracts the 12 and returns as 8.. 

Can u help from here?

Comment: My new answer look similar to this except some minor difference. Can you edit the question so that it is well formatted. It is tough for me to read anyway

Comment: The following is the query i tested last and urs is also not working well . may be i would have given the wrong table names for the query.. find the names of the table i have used in the below query

select a.pid, a.amount - b.amount from 
(select product_id as pid, COALESCE(sum(quantity),0) amount 
from purchase_details group by product_id) a, 
(select product_id as pid, COALESCE(sum(quantity), 0) amount 
from invoice_details group by product_id) b group by a.pid;